# What is BruteForce layer in TensorFlow and why is it called BruteForce

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

I understand the task of retrieval - I have gone through the code; also looked into alternative approaches like SCNN which is an ultra-fast nearest neighbor.

However, I still have hard time understanding the mechanism of the following code

```
# Create a model that takes in raw query features, and
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model.user_model)
# recommends movies out of the entire movies dataset.
index.index_from_dataset(
  tf.data.Dataset.zip((movies.batch(100), movies.batch(100).map(model.movie_model)))
)

# Get recommendations.
_, titles = index(tf.constant(["42"]))
print(f"Recommendations for user 42: {titles[0, :3]}")
```

`model.user_model` is trained and by now should return embeddings of user_id. The input for `BruteForce` layer is `model.user_model`; and then it should be indexed ?

I guess the output is given `user_id` 42, return 3 titles, out of that `movies.batch(100)`. but I can't understand the function of BruteForce and indexing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BruteForce layer tests all the combinations between embeddings that are extracted from the last layer of the model.

According to the  [tensorflow documentation for the layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/api_docs/python/tfrs/layers/factorized_top_k/BruteForce) the layer retuns the index of the **top k** results (by default 10) indexes that are the closest to each index.

Comment: is it possible to print the values of the variable ```index```?

Comment: use ._candidates, ._identifiers

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood as "The input for BruteForce layer is model.user_model". user_model in not the input for BureteForce layer. It is the parameter of ButeForce class. so "input" is the instance of BruteForce. user_model is the query_model to embed the inputs and one of the two tower.

And index.index_from_dataset() set the embeddings of the another tower candidates.

And movies.batch(100) does not output just 100 movies, but it outputs many chunks of 100 movies.